# Azure Durable Function Send EventPostUri by mail

Tags: http, email, azure-functions, uri, azure-durable-functions

I build a durable function for user provisioning in azure ad.
My aim is an orchestration function which check for available licenses. If all licenses are in use, the function wait for an external event and retry the license assignment.

To realize this, I want to send an eMail with the request to buy new licenses and the "SendEventPostUri".

My problem is that I can't find a way to read the SendEventPostUri in an orchestration function.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can get the [`SendEventPostUri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.durabletask.httpmanagementpayload.sendeventposturi?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_WebJobs_Extensions_DurableTask_HttpManagementPayload_SendEventPostUri) via the [`CreateHttpManagementPayload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.durabletask.idurableorchestrationclient.createhttpmanagementpayload?view=azure-dotnet) method of the `IDurableOrchestrationClient` interface.

The format of the URI is as follows

```
http://host/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/instanceId/raiseEvent/{eventName}?taskHub=TestHubName&connection=Storage&code=*****
```

and you would need to replace the `{eventName}` for the event you need to raise.

Here is sample code that I used to check this

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace csharp_durable_funk
{
  public class RaiseEvent
  {
    [FunctionName("GetSendEventPostUriOrchestrator")]
    public async Task<string> RunOrchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient durableClient,
        ILogger log)
    {
      await context.CallActivityAsync("GetSendEventPostUriOrchestrator_Hello", null);

      return durableClient.CreateHttpManagementPayload(context.InstanceId).SendEventPostUri;
    }

    [FunctionName("GetSendEventPostUriOrchestrator_Hello")]
    public string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
    {
      return $"Hello {name}!";
    }

    [FunctionName("GetSendEventPostUri")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient durableClient,
        ILogger log)
    {
      string instanceId = await durableClient.StartNewAsync("GetSendEventPostUriOrchestrator");

      return await durableClient.WaitForCompletionOrCreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(req, instanceId);
    }
  }
}
```